# Class File Editor - Source not found error in Eclipse 2020-12

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I am unable to see the class files and cannot attach the required file in the specified path. How to resolve this situation? for me. I tried all the solutions related to it all over stack overflow but to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a Java JDK installed or just a JRE? You need to JDK to see the source.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes I have jdk 15 installed and configured. I tested it on the command line and its working fine. Programs and compiling and running fine but only class file editor is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you actually told Eclipse about the JDK in Preferences > Java > Installed JREs? Is the JDK set as the JVM to use for the project in the Project Build Path.

Comment: You also seem to be running your application with **1.8** and not 15. Is that also a JDK?

Comment: @greg-449 I tried that and checked the path too but no change.

Comment: @nitind Yes it's a JDK too. But apparently it isn't working to get the class data.

Comment: What's the path to the JVM it's using from that JDK?